# React-Router-DOM "Exact" Path only working for top-level (/)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm following the `react-router-dom` example in this sample app: https://codesandbox.io/s/vVoQVk78

There is a routing defined on the `Main` component, which can display either a `Home/Roster/Schedule` subcomponent:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
    <Route path='/roster' component={Roster}/>
    <Route path='/schedule' component={Schedule}/>
</Switch>
```

The `Roster` sub-component has its own routing and can display either `FullRoster` or `Player`:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/roster' component={FullRoster}/>
    <Route path='/roster/:number' component={Player}/>
</Switch>
```

The example works, but if I make all of my routes `exact`, the Player sub-sub-component stops working:

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
    <Route exact path='/roster' component={Roster}/>
    <Route exact path='/schedule' component={Schedule}/>
</Switch>
..
```

Why can't I designate all of my routes as **exact**? An exact `/` is separate from an exact `/roster` and from an exact `/roster/:number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exact` means that your path should match exactly with your route path and should not be just the prefix of it.

so when you define `/roster` to be exact, The roster component does not render on `/roster/1` and since Roster component doesn't render, the routes defined within it cannot render

However, you if you don't use `exact` prop on the Route, `/roster/1` matches `/roster` and renders the `Roster` component. Now within the Roster component you define a route `/roster/:number` so it matches that too and renders the `Player` component within the `Roster` component